# can we use multi-gpu traing to restore a model which is trained by a single gpu?

Tags: tensorflow

when I use multi gpu load the model which is trained by single,I get this error message:

> Tensor name "test_mutli_gpu_1/test_mutli_gpu_1/Mean/avg" not found in checkpoint files models_0606/my_modle-50

here is my pseudo about graph code:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  a = tf.get_variable()
for gpu_index in range(0,4):
  with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % gpu_index):
    with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % ('test_mutli_gpu', gpu_index)) as scope:
      tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
      loss = caculateloss()
      grad = calculategard()
      grads.append(grad )
 grad = average_gradients(grads)
 apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads)
 variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY)
 variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
 train_op = tf.group(apply_gradient_op, variables_averages_op)
```

anybody know whether I mess something in multi gpu training
many thanks~

Comment: Can you please add the code you use to load the graph from the checkpoint?

Comment: it's simple just one code:saver.restore(sess,"models_0606/my_modle-650")

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer,commonly speak **if you trained a model with single GPU, you can't continue training your model with mutiple GPU**.

> loss_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9, name='loss')
>     loss_averages_op = loss_averages.apply(losses + [total_loss])

in my caculateloss() function, this operation will generate a variable with prename about your **gpu_idx** 
either you could do some test about cifair_multi_train.py